# How to Get Address of Last Value From Data Section?

Tags: linux, assembly

I am using 'as' assembler with following .section .data

```
items:
.long 5,6,8,10
```

how to get address of value 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use assembler directive `.` for get your current location address or you can use something like `lea items(,%rax, 4), %rdi` to load `%rax`th location address of items array into `%rdi`.

Comment: Thanks, still learning about addressing mode. How to use the `.` ?

Comment: It's assembler directive for example you can use it to get your string length as macro : `.equ len, . - string` after that len equal to your string length. note that assembler directive  like macro in c and so all your assembler directive compute and replace at assembly phase of your compilation process. for example if you use `movq len, %rax` it replace with `movq 10, %rax`.

Answer (score 2):

*How to use the . ?*

The dot-symbol (standing alone) refers to the current address, when GAS comes to that point to assemble. Other assemblers use the '$'-character.

Example:

```
...
.data
...
items:  .long 5,6,8,10      # Every ".long" is 4 bytes long
lastitem = . - 4            # https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Dot.html#Dot
...

.text
...
    movl (lastitem), %eax
...
```